# Import entire HTML page into another page

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, html-imports

I'm trying to embed another website within my website but I don't want to do it with an iFrame or AJAX import due to some issues that would cause.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="import" href="mysite.html">
</head>
  <body>
    <script>
 var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
    var content = link.import;
    document.body.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically I'm trying to do this with HTML Imports from Web Components but unfortunately what I have above does not work (I am using the right browser too) and all the examples I've found were only for importing a specific div or element from within an imported page. But is it possible to simply load the entire page and embed it in another site?

Comment: Yes, but you won't be able to execute JavaScript on the other site page without CORS access.

Comment: Yeah I did make sure to enable CORS already. I just haven't been able to embed the site into my web page using the code I have above. It doesn't seem to load anything.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `var el = content.querySelector('html');
document.body.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));`?

Comment: That only loads a specific div from the page nor do I have anything named warning in my html page. I'm trying to load the entire page, embed it into my site but without using an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the object you get from the `import` property of the `<link rel="import">` element is a [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface.
You cannot insert this type of object inside a `<body>` element.

Instead you should at least get the `<html>` element of the imported document from its [`documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) property:

```
 var content = link.import.documentElement  //returns a html element
```

But it still incorrect because you will then insert a `<html>` element inside a `<body>` element, which is ugly.

You'd rather copy the innerHTML text of the imported document to the main one:

```
 document.body.innerHTML = link.import.querySelector( 'body' ).innerHTML
```

Or put the HTML you want to import inside a `<template>`, which is better if you want to defer scripts execution and loadings.